# JS variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following function:

```
function initPaymentBlock(bIdx) {  

    var paymentType = 'default';
    if( $('#gc-apply-btn-'+bIdx).length ) {
        $('#gc-apply-btn-'+bIdx).click( function() { 
            poApplyGiftCard(bIdx); 
            console.log("about to change payment type");
            paymentType = 'credit card';
            console.log("paymentType inside function: " + paymentType);
        });
    }

    console.log("payment type: " + paymentType);
    poGetPaymentOption(paymentType, 0, bIdx);

}
```

The `paymentType` variable is set to 'default' inside the initial statement. Inside the internal click function, it's changed to 'credit card'. When I run the `console.log` statement inside the internal function, it returns `credit card`. The `console.log` outside the internal function (right before the `poGetPaymentOption` call) returns 'default'.

I know the issue is the scope of the variable, but can't figure out how or where I can set it so that the `poGetPaymentOption` function call gets the correct value ('default' if the button isn't clicked before it's run; 'credit card' if the button is clicked.) Can someone help me out?

Comment: Put `poGetPaymentOption` inside the click event? It really depends on what you are trying to do and WHEN you are trying to do it.

Comment: Can't. There are other functions defined in the main function, and that one needs to be called after all of them. Don't want to have to repeat it by putting a call in each internal function.

Comment: Well if that is the case then `paymentType` will always be its initial value when `poGetPaymentOption` gets run because it can't change until someone clicks something, and from what you just said `poGetPaymentOption` gets run when `initPaymentBlock` gets run.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty obvious. The click changes the value but only after the click. Your second console log runs before a click event is fired. What is wrong with this?

```
function initPaymentBlock(bIdx) {  

    var paymentType = 'default';
    if( $('#gc-apply-btn-'+bIdx).length ) {
        $('#gc-apply-btn-'+bIdx).click( function() { 
            poApplyGiftCard(bIdx); 
            console.log("about to change payment type");
            paymentType = 'credit card';
            console.log("paymentType inside function: " + paymentType);
            poGetPaymentOption(paymentType, 0, bIdx);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with scope.  It's all about the order of execution.

Here is how the code executes:

- When you enter the initPaymentBlock function, you set it to 'default'.
- Then you create a click handler that will change its value to 'credit card', but ONLY AFTER somebody clicks a button.
- Then your console output at the bottom puts out the current value, which is still 'default'.
- Now, if the user clicks the button, the click handler will execute and it will output 'credit card'

Here is the expected console output when you run `initPaymentBlock()`:

- payment type: default

That's it.  Now when you click the button, the following output will show:

- about to change payment type
- paymentType inside function: credit card

Comment: The problem is that even if you DO click the button, the console output at the bottom still displays default, not credit card.

Comment: The console output at the bottom only executes once, at the initial call of the `initPaymentBlock` function.  It never executes again after the button click.

Comment: But it doesn't. That's what I'm saying. It NEVER puts out 'credit card', even when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Well, that's not what it sounded like from your original question.  There you stated: "When I run the console.log statement inside the internal function, it returns credit card."

Comment: When the user clicks the button, what does the console show?  Does it output: "about to change payment type" at least?